# matlab: limiting erosion on binary images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-morphology

I am trying to erode objects in a binary image such that they do not become smaller than some fixed size. Consider, for instance, a binary map composed of connected components (blobs), wherein one defines blob size by either the minimal or maximal antipolar (anti-perimetric) distance (i.e., the distance between two points that are as far from one another as they can be on the perimeter or contour of the blob; if the contour consists of N consecutively numbered points, then the distances evaluated would be those between points 1 and N/2+1, points 2 and N/2+2, etc.). Given such an arrangement, I seek to erode these blobs until the distance metric reaches a specified limit. If the blobs were simple circles, then the effect could be realized by ultimate erosion followed by dilation to a fixed size; however, the contour of an irregular object would be lost by such a procedure. Is there a way to achieve such an effect for connected, irregular components using built-in functions in MATLAB?

Comment: Can you be more specific and put some images ?

Answer (score 0):

With no image and already tried code presented I can understand you wrong, but may be iterative using bwmorph with 'thin','skel' or 'shrink' will help you.

```
while(cond < cond_threshold)
    bw=bwmorph(bw,...,1); %one of the options above
    cond = calc_cond(bw);
end
```